# Ways to improve Auto Suggest from client Side

Tags: javascript, search, solr, autocomplete, full-text-search

I have a search service that has Apache Solr at the backend and client makes an AJAX call to the webservice which fetches data through Solr and gives me the result. I am searching for ways to make this faster then what it is right now. The auto suggest gives categories in suggestion which are total 1,20,000 (text value i.e name)

**Efforts**

1. I made a txt file (on the server )and upon search it fetches the entire categories in a javascript variable in which I find the .indexOf() to find the substr position (which user enters), sort the indexes and provide auto suggest.
2. I have thought to make a json file and implement something similar to what i have done above.
3. Also made a drop down through  which auto filters the content upon typing but I read alot that it is not much recommended to use it.

The txt file made is of size 2MB and I also have to take care of 2G and other low bandwidth internet users. My main aim is not to hit the DB again and again on every user key press.

Answer (score 0):

To make the response fast, I suggest cache the indexes in-memory. Indexing 1,20,000 categories may not be huge. Also you can try Redis's [autocomplete](http://autocomplete.redis.io/). This would easy to implement and would have very fast response time.

Comment: If someone only has to work client side, i.e. he gets the data through Solr (Which I assume is the fastest till date) how can more optimizations on client side can be done?

Comment: To optimize on client side, you can cache the data if data is not huge. You can use Web storage to store data locally on browser (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Local_and_session_storage). When browser loads your page for first time, it would be slow since it would cache. But if data changes on server side, you must refresh this cache. Solr may not be fastest. I think if you cache in-memory on server side it would fastest. Also depends on how you structure indices.